# Clearing 3ds Max model rotation

Tags: three.js, 3dsmax

I imported models from 3ds Max in THREE.js after having converted them to JSON using `convert_obj_three.py`. The models retain their rotation from the 3ds Max file. I want the models without any rotation applied to them. Is there any way to reset the rotation to zero in Three.js (or 3ds Max, for that matter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3dsmax simply set the transform of the object to the default matrix.

```
$.transform = matrix3 1
```

This will zero out the translation, rotation and scale.
If you only want to reset the rotation, use:

```
$.rotation = eulerangles 0 0 0
```

These are of course MAXScript methods. If you want to reset manually you can simply enter zeroes in the transform type-in box (or right-click the spinners).